# Nginx - Flask app and css asset not loaded correctly

Tags: python, css, nginx, flask, assets

I have a flask app which has both front and back ends. I am using flask_assets to serve both css and js assets.

```
assets = Environment()
assets.init_app(app)


js = Bundle(common_blueprint.name + '/dist/javascripts/scout.js', output='dist/javascripts/scout.js')
css = Bundle(common_blueprint.name + '/dist/stylesheets/base.css', output='dist/stylesheets/scout.css')


assets.register("js_all", js)
assets.register("css_all", css)


app.register_blueprint(common_blueprint)
```

Now are are running in a weird issue, every time I deploy the app and hit the url, the application doesn't load the css file. 
After few browser hard refreshes the css file is served correctly.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason to use `flask_assets` I suggest you to store both js and css files under the folder **static** in your flask project folder with the structure:

```
FLASK_PROJECT/static/javascripts/    # for your js files
FLASK_PROJECT/static/stylesheets/    # for your css files
```

Then in your **index.html** / **base.html** file you would load the files as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='stylesheets/scout.css') }}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='javascripts/scout.js') }}"></script>
```

For more information you can take a look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files)